# Javascript - return statement misunderstood

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have the following code:

```
function a(){
    b();
    return undefined;
}

function b(){
    c = function(){ };
    return c;
}
a();
console.log(c); //Why can we see it?
```

I will tell you how I see this more or less, and please correct me where I am wrong:

first a is executing, and a new execution context is created.
while a's execution is processing, it also executes b function, so there's
a new execution context created.

b's execution context  returns c, which is a function, back to a's execution context.
now b's execution context is over, execution stack is back with a,
and it sees: "return undefined".

Well, now a's execution context is returning undefined back to the caller. Now what I don't understand, is how the c function still exists( You can see it with console.log(c);  ), and more so, why is it attached to the window object?
To my understanding(which is wrong somewhere, I know) it was supposed to be garbage-collected
once a's execution context was over, since it held c's function reference.

the return statement seems to have weird rules, I would like some clarification. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You've declared `c` on a global scope. It's not bound to `b()`

Answer (score 3):

It's because you made `c` a global variable (and all global variables live on the window object in the browser context). If you initialize it properly, you won't see it in the console:

```
function a(){
    b();
    return undefined;
}

function b(){
    var c = function(){ }; // var = local scope only
    return c;
}
a();
console.log(c); // No longer can see it, undefined error as expected
```

---

**UPDATE** / further explanation

Since your title mentions the return statement, I'd just like to add that this has **nothing to do with function returns**, but only with **variable declarations**. Your code would behave identically without any return statements because you're not using function return values like, for example:

```
console.log(b()); // will output the value of c,
                  // which is what function b returns
                  // and it doesn't matter if c is global or local
                  // (but try always to use local)
```